# S3 write concurrency using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I have a suspicion we are hitting an S3 write concurrency issue with an AWS Glue job. I am testing 10 DPUs writing 10k objects, 1 MB each (~10 GB total) and it is taking 2+ hours for just the write stage of the job. It seems like across 10 DPUs I should be able to distribute good enough to get much better throughput. I am hitting several different bucket prefixes and do not think I'm getting throttled by S3 or anything.

I see that my job is using EMRFS (the default S3 FileSystem API implementation for Glue), so that is good for write throughput from my understanding. I found some suggestions that say to adjust `fs.s3.maxConnections`, `hive.mv.files.threads` and set `hive.blobstore.use.blobstore.as.scratchdir = false`.

1. Where can I see what the current settings for these are in my Glue jobs and how can I configure them? While I see many settings and configurations in the Spark UI logs I can generate from my jobs, I'm not finding these settings.
2. How can I see what actual S3 write concurrency I'm getting in each worker in the job? Is this something I can see in the Spark UI logs or is there another metric somewhere that would show this?